# Jenkins - Textarea parameter plugin set default value from property file?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to find jenkins parameter plugins to do;

- Editible textbox (multiline)
- Set default text from property file (something like groovy script)

Can you please suggest any plugins?

I tried `Active chioce parameter` plugin, `Extended choice parameter` plugin. But those are only provide `choice` option not textarea.
And `Dynamic parameter` plugin also seems not support multi-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists a way in jenkis jobs configuration to pass text parameter to execute a job. Adding Text Parameter, you can define a simple text multiline parameter, where users can enter a text value, which you can use during a build, either as an environment variable, or through variable substitution in some other parts of the configuration.

To define parameters for your job select "This build is parameterized", then using the drop-down button to add as many text parameters or other type as you need.

more info look at

[Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

Comment: Dear johnny. Thank you for the note. Addition to the Text Parameter, I want to set default value to it, which from specific file. Contents of the file can be changed. Is it possible/

Comment: Dear @Dorr You can build a program that reads the file and copy the content in a env variable and use it as default value into the default value field of text param - > ${FILE_CONTENT}. I dont know how big is the file. but if the file has reasonable size, env var may be a workaround